# What are the meta fields for an attachment?

Tags: functions, images, post-meta, attachments

I'm trying to find all the meta fields that are used for an attachment: like Title, alternative text, description and caption . I've looked all over and the only one I was able to find was for an Alternative text, which is `_wp_attachment_image_alt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily inspect all the metadata for any post like so:

```php
// 123 is the (attachment) post ID
var_dump( get_post_meta( 123 ) );
```

And in a default WordPress setup with no plugins or theme which add custom metadata to the image attachment post, the metadata you'd get are:

- [`_wp_attached_file`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_attached_file/) — string, the image file (path and name) for the attachment post
- [`_wp_attachment_metadata`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_metadata/) — array (serialized), the sizes for the image like 'thumbnail' (including original size), and metadata from [EXIF/IPTC info](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_read_image_metadata/).
- `_wp_attachment_image_alt` — string, the image's alternative text

As for the other details like the image title, they are in the post data (in the posts database table), so you can for example use [`wp_update_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_post/) to update these details:

- `post_title` — image title
- `post_excerpt` — [image caption](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_caption/)
- `post_content` — image description